# VB.NET Trigger when year chages for example from 2014 to 2015

Tags: vb.net, command

I am trying to find out how i can write a command that it will make a certain operation when the system automatically understands that the year is changed!Like for example on 1st of January of 2016 that the year will change from 2015 to 2016.

Comment: Could you not set a scheduled task for 01/01/{year} repeating annually?

Comment: Or create a timer and check every second if the year has changed?